# Create action not saving data on the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've a simple Ruby on Rails Application trying to save a country list into a country

Here's my new and create actions

```
def new
    @country = Country.new
  end

  def create
    @country = Country.new(country_params)
    if @country.save
      flash[:notice] = "Country created successfully"
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end
```

Here's the private params

```
private
  def country_params
    params.require(:country).permit(:country_name)
  end
```

The issue is that the country data is not being saved. Neither am I getting any errors.
The development log for the create actions reads as follows:

```
Started GET "/countries/new?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=Df5d6Z0Gz9CkpHdgXypfR0dnxMkm0oImKP3Uq3UdP4Y%3D&country%5Bcountry_name%5D=Ukraine&commit=Create+country" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-17 12:49:59 -0500
Processing by CountriesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Df5d6Z0Gz9CkpHdgXypfR0dnxMkm0oImKP3Uq3UdP4Y=", "country"=>{"country_name"=>"Ukraine"}, "commit"=>"Create country"}
  Rendered countries/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 115ms (Views: 114.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I'm also adding the view template, since the problem started happening after adding the view.

```
<div class= "container">
    <div class="row">
        <%= link_to("Back to list", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'btn btn-primary margin-bottom') %>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="form-inline">
            <%=  form_for(:country, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
            <%= f.label(:country_name, 'Name:', :class => 'control-label') %>
            <%= f.text_field(:country_name, :class => 'form-control') %>
            <%= submit_tag('Create country', :class=>'btn btn-success') %>
            <%end %>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>


</div>
```

Added the default route that I'm using

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Comment: Please post piece of `development.log` where you call create action.

Comment: Please post logs where have `sql` insert operations.

Comment: We need the `create` logs, not the `new` logs.

Comment: This is not the new log, it is the create log

Comment: Are you sure since it clearly says that it is getting the `#new` action. Can you verify your form is submitting to the create action and not just re-requesting the new action. This could be a form or routing issue.

Comment: looks like in form you have path to `new` action instead `create`.

Comment: In your controller, do a `puts 'Creating!'` as the first line in the create method. The line in your logs `Processing by CountriesController#new as HTML` says it isn't going to the action you think

Comment: I tried using the puts creating, but it doesn't show it on the console, which means it isn't going into the correct controller. Any idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Writing here since in the comments we don't get nice formatting:

Let's make it easier. I assume your controller is called 
`CountriesController` so: Remove that default route & add `resources :countries` in your routes. Next, in the form:

```
<%=  form_for(@country, url: countries_path) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Now you should see in the logs that you are making a POST request. You can install any debugging gem like pry-rails, and type at the beginning of the create action `binding.pry` and you'll get a better idea of what's going on there